# How to use Independent set problem for image edge detection?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, image-processing

Let's say an Image is given, We have to convert the image into a matrix by using grayscale values for each pixel and then convert that matrix into a graph and use independent set problem to detect edges

[image: This is an example of an image converted to a matrix]
I was able to figure out how to make a graph from an image using this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224737408_A_unified_method_for_segmentation_and_edge_detection_using_graph_theory but I can't figure out how to use independent set problem.